# Extracting a Symbol from a return value of a function

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Using macros I want to get a general solution for referring to `Symbol`s of fields and subfields of a case class data tree.

Inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/4542402), I've created a following skeleton:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.macros.Context

object SubRef {

  case class SubRef[ SourceT, TargetT ]( symbol : Symbol )

  implicit def functionToSubRef
    [ SourceT, TargetT ]
    ( f : SourceT => TargetT ) 
    : SubRef[ SourceT, TargetT ]
    = macro functionToSubRefMacro[ SourceT, TargetT ]

  def functionToSubRefMacro
    [ SourceT : c.WeakTypeTag, TargetT : c.WeakTypeTag ]
    ( c : Context )
    ( f : c.Expr[ SourceT => TargetT ] )
    : c.Expr[ SubRef[ SourceT, TargetT ] ]
    = ???

}
```

I expect this solution to work like so:

```
case class A( b : B )
case class B( c : Int )

val ref : SubRef[ A, Int ] = _.b.c
```

The macro conversion should fail if the passed in function:

- Is not a single expression
- Does not return a value of a symbol, which is a subfield of the source symbol, i.e., the `targetSymbol.owner[.owner...] == sourceSymbol`

What should the missing macro implementation be?

Comment: I don't think this will work without untyped macros. `_.b.c` will not typecheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your notation won't work in 2.10 as pointed out by Simon, writing this macro should be easy. It looks like you already know how to perform validation, so I'll omit that part.

The real challenge here is converting a compile-time reflection artifact (`c.universe.Symbol`) to a runtime reflection artifact (`ru.Symbol`). This can be done via reification. There are already `c.reifyTree` and `c.reifyType`, which do this for trees and types, but `c.reifySymbol` doesn't exist yet.

Luckily symbol reification should be very easy to implement. Just wrap your symbol in an Ident, i.e. write `Ident(sym)`, and then call `c.reifyTree` on the result. Then at runtime you just extract a symbol from the wrapping tree and you're done.

P.S. Right now I don't have time to write the code that does all these things. If anyone of you guys implements the macro and posts the code, I'll gladly remove my answer and upvote you :)

Comment: Do you mean that the only way it will work is if I write `val ref : SubRef[ A, Int ] = ( a : A ) => a.b.c`? But why? The following unmacroed code compiles just fine: `val f : A => Int = _.b.c`. If this is the issue, are there any workarounds for this possible (or when will it become possible)? Using the `_.b.c` notation kinda makes the whole point of this macro.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov `_.b.c` doesn't have a type. The lhs denotes a type you want after the implicit conversion is applied but to call the implicit you already need a type. Implicit untyped macros will even not work because there must be a type before the implicit can be called. I think the closest example that will work is to call an untyped macro explicitly `ref(_.b.c)`

Comment: @sschaef Thanks. Such a pity. This could have been a quite useful universal solution. I guess I got spoiled by Haskell's type inferer. I don't understand what's the difficulty for Scala's compiler to choose the correct implicit conversion from the target type, which specifies both the input and output of it.